# Power BI API - get dataset by ID

Tags: powerbi

One of the Power BI APIs is to get dataset by ID. Can someone shed light on the command syntax to get a table of a dataset from a workspace please? Thank you.

GET https://api.powerbi.com/groups/{workspace ID}/datasets/{dataset ID}/{TableName} ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to get table's schema (list of columns), currently the API does not provide a way to do this. Probably the presumption is that this dataset is created using the API, so you should know what you created. If you want to get a list of tables in a dataset, you can use `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}/tables` like this:

```
    private void GetDatasetById(string accessToken, string groupId, string datasetId)
    {
        string powerBIDatasetsApiUrl = $"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}/tables";

        var request = WebRequest.Create(powerBIDatasetsApiUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
        using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to call the API using Javascript like jquery in a webpage and get the data of a dataset, not just the column names. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Possibly you can get the data source and read the data directly from there. Or embed a tile with a table in your site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GetTables method to retrieve tables and their corresponding metadata but it only supports push datasets.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_gettables

When using .NET client, the syntax would be:

```
using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(_apiUrl), _credentials))
{
    var tables = client.Datasets.GetTables(_datasetId);
}
```